# IEEE 754: sqrtf() with fesetround(): different results between compilers: 0x42440a72 vs. 0x42440a73

Tags: c, floating-point, rounding, ieee-754, cl

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <fenv.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    typedef union { uint32_t u; float f; } ufloat;
    ufloat val;
    float arg = 2401.999999;
    int r;
    r = fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD);
    val.f = sqrtf(arg);
    printf ("FE_DOWNWARD   %22.13a [0x%x] %d\n", val.f, val.u, r);
    r = fesetround(FE_TONEAREST);
    val.f = sqrtf(arg);
    printf ("FE_TONEAREST  %22.13a [0x%x] %d\n", val.f, val.u, r);
    r = fesetround(FE_TOWARDZERO);
    val.f = sqrtf(arg);
    printf ("FE_TOWARDZERO %22.13a [0x%x] %d\n", val.f, val.u, r);
    r = fesetround(FE_UPWARD);
    val.f = sqrtf(arg);
    printf ("FE_UPWARD     %22.13a [0x%x] %d\n", val.f, val.u, r);
    return 0;
}
```

Host: Win10 x64.

Results:

Case 1.

```
$ clang t2.c -o t2.clang.exe && ./t2.clang.exe
FE_DOWNWARD     0x1.8814e60000000p+5 [0x42440a73] 0
FE_TONEAREST    0x1.8814e60000000p+5 [0x42440a73] 0
FE_TOWARDZERO   0x1.8814e60000000p+5 [0x42440a73] 0
FE_UPWARD       0x1.8814e60000000p+5 [0x42440a73] 0
 
$ clang --version
clang version 8.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_801/final)
```

Case 2.

```
$ gcc t2.c -o t2.gcc.exe && ./t2.gcc.exe
FE_DOWNWARD     0x1.8814e60000000p+5 [0x42440a73] 0
FE_TONEAREST    0x1.8814e60000000p+5 [0x42440a73] 0
FE_TOWARDZERO   0x1.8814e60000000p+5 [0x42440a73] 0
FE_UPWARD       0x1.8814e60000000p+5 [0x42440a73] 0
 
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 10.2.0
```

Case 3.

```
cl t2.c && t2
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.25.28611 for x64
...
FE_DOWNWARD     0x1.8814e40000000p+5 [0x42440a72] 0
FE_TONEAREST    0x1.8814e60000000p+5 [0x42440a73] 0
FE_TOWARDZERO   0x1.8814e40000000p+5 [0x42440a72] 0
FE_UPWARD       0x1.8814e60000000p+5 [0x42440a73] 0
```

Case 4.

```
cl t2.c && t2
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.25.28611 for x86
...
The system cannot execute the specified program.
Pop-up window appears: "Virus & thread protection: Windows Defender Antivirus found threats. Get details."
```

Case 5.

```
wandbox.org: gcc HEAD 11.0.0 20200
$ gcc prog.c -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 "-lm"
FE_DOWNWARD     0x1.8814e40000000p+5 [0x42440a72] 0
FE_TONEAREST    0x1.8814e60000000p+5 [0x42440a73] 0
FE_TOWARDZERO   0x1.8814e40000000p+5 [0x42440a72] 0
FE_UPWARD       0x1.8814e60000000p+5 [0x42440a73] 0
```

Case 6.

```
wandbox.org: clang HEAD 12.0.0
$ clang prog.c -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu11 "-lm"
FE_DOWNWARD     0x1.8814e40000000p+5 [0x42440a72] 0
FE_TONEAREST    0x1.8814e60000000p+5 [0x42440a73] 0
FE_TOWARDZERO   0x1.8814e40000000p+5 [0x42440a72] 0
FE_UPWARD       0x1.8814e60000000p+5 [0x42440a73] 0
```

Questions:

1. Why there are different results (`0x42440a72` vs. `0x42440a73`) between compilers?
2. How to get the same results between compilers?

Comment: You can - and must post those - just don't put *everything as a code block*. Format the headings of the separate runs as normal text!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, thanks for the hint (using `<pre>code</pre>` pattern)!

Comment: Changing floating-point rounding modes is not well supported by some compilers and libraries, but one problem in your source code is that the C standard does not define the behavior if you change rounding modes with `FENV_ACCESS` off (C 2018 7.6.1 2). You can turn it on with `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON` in compilers that support it.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that in case of `FENV_ACCESS` off we cannot rely on `fesetround()` return value because of UB? In the example above `fesetround()` does [falsely] return `0` (i.e. rounding direction was successfully set), but from the results we see that rounding direction was not set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why there are different results (0x42440a72 vs. 0x42440a73) between compilers?

At least with older gcc, `<fenv.h>` support not required.

See [floating-point environment access in <fenv.h>, Library feature, no compiler support required.](https://gcc.gnu.org/c99status.html)

When I compile with "GNU C11 (GCC) version 9.3.0 (x86_64-pc-cygwin)", the below

```
#include <fenv.h>
#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON
```

I receive the below:

```
warning: ignoring #pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS [-Wunknown-pragmas]
```

See also [If pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS is absent, does it mean default rounding mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60716929/2410359), [pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33471254/2410359)

> How to get the same results between compilers?

Not that helpful, but do not use optional features of `fenv.h` or avoid select compilers.

There may exist a gcc compile time flag to help, but I am not aware of one.

Also use `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON` [@Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63870900/ieee-754-sqrtf-with-fesetround-different-results-between-compilers-0x4244/63872312#comment112944816_63870900).  This may not solve this issue, but prevent related ones.

Comment: Both gcc and clang do not support `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON`. gcc: `warning: ignoring '#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS'`, clang: `warning: pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON is not supported`. For clang it seems that there is a patch: https://reviews.llvm.org/D69272. For cl: need to use `#pragma fenv_access (on)`.